# what is meant by client.on() and explain the below code?

Tags: redis

```
1.var redis = require("redis");
2.var client = redis.createClient();
3.client.on("error", function (err) {
4. console.log("Error " + err);
5.});
```

I cannot understand the redis thing in node js application.
can anyone explain the above one line by line?

Answer (score 1):

The first line requires a module named "redis" using the CommonJS syntax. This is a basic way of loading functionality in Nodejs.

The second lines creates a new object, client, which is returned by the "redis module". The object "client" exposes an interface that lets the program listens to events, which is a core concept in Nodejs.

The third line simply listens to an error-event, which the redis-client may throw when something goes bad.

For more information about events in Nodejs,
https://nodejs.org/api/events.html

For more information about modules in Nodejs, 
https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html